# How to save Shipping Method in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to save Free Shipping method with the order save by the following way:

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'checkmo'));
try {
     $checkout->saveOrder();
 }
 catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
 }
```

but the shipping method is not getting saved. It's showing

> No shipping information available

Even though the payment method is saved properly but the Shipping Method is not.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Where are you executing this code? Is the quote address set correctly? Shipping methods need an address to work.

Comment: Please check if freeshipping is active or not, if it is active then check your order is eligible for freeshipping or not.